# C# memory dispose - NetworkInterface

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, network-interface

So basically I made a simple service using Topshelf which checks for NIC status and info every X seconds using timer and NetworkInterface class.

Without NetworkInterface, the service runs **idle**, but any use of the NetworkInterface class keeps incrementing memory ( in very small amount).
Example:

```
public static void checkNIC()
{
    if (!NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()) // This keeps incrementing memory
                    return;
    
    foreach (NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()) // This one as well
    {
    }
}
```

Calling GC improves it, but I believe if service keeps running for a long time (days), the memory will be incremented by a lot.

Am I missing something here?
Thanks.

Comment: When you run a .NET program, memory will often seems to increase over time. Eventually, your code and the garbage collector will likely find and equilibrium and your memory usage will bounce around it. If you are using something like _Task Manager_, then you're looking at a wrong measure. Use _Performance Monitor_ with the .NET memory counters. But, you probably really don't need to worry about it. Read the `NetworkInterface` docs to find the right calling pattern (is it _Disposable_, when should you Dispose it, etc). But, you really shouldn't worry unless you see a problem (which you haven't)

Comment: `NetworkInterface` (and the underlying `SystemNetworkInterface`) is just a wrapper that mainly calls `iphlpapi.dll` functions. It just stores values, no unmanaged resources to dispose, so it doesn't have a `Dispose()` method to call. If there's no memory pressure, the GC won't come by until it *fells like it*.

Comment: Oh I see, so basically you are saying I shouldn't worry about it because it's managed resources, in some time garbage will be disposed and handle automatically. And yes I was checking it in task manager. Alright, I think I'd have to test it running for a long duration to see the result.